# Disabling Windows Defender via registry, group policy, rename it's folder or deleting it from the %SystemRoot% doesn't work, how do I solve it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

Recently (at least from build 2004 on, I didn't notice if it was an issue before) Microsoft has added the "nice" feature that makes it impossible to disable Windows Defender at all.

All methods that used to work don't anymore. I tried disabling it at Settings, it kept re-enabling itself, I disabled the Anti-Scram feature, it kept turning itself on, I tried the group policy trick, but the Windows Defender option is no longer there.
I also edited the registry entries - one can easily find them on google - which usually did the trick, nothing. I even booted from a live USB stick and renamed the Windows Defender folder, didn't work. I then went further and booted again from the Live USB stick, searched for "Windows Defender" under "C:\Windows" and deleted all I could find. That disabled the virus analyses and most other Windows Defender features, ***but real time protection kept working*** (just don't ask me how).

I could no longer launch hacks or the likes, because if I enabled my antivirus, it would block it, if I disable it, Windows Defender comes in and blocks it. Telling it to ignore that file does nothing either.
How do I solve this? I just want to launch anything I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's a real issue in the latest Windows 10 builds. Microsoft made it impossible to disable it and made sure that every trick out in the internet doesn't work.

The workaround is simple, however. Beyond what one would expect, actually.

**You just have to add .EXE *(or other executable formats you want to launch)* to Windows Defender's exclusions!**

You do that by first disabling your antivirus (otherwise Windows Defender won't show the exclusion option AFAIK) and then to the path (actual labels might differ, my PC is not in English) `Start Menu> Settings> Security and Updates> Windows Security > Virus and threats protection > Manage Settings`  and then under the `Exclusions` label click `"Add or Remove Exclusion"` and click `"Add Exclusion>Filetype"` and put .EXE there, it will ignore any file there.

If that doesn't work, select the `"Add Directory"` option and add your whole C or any other drives you have there and be done with it.

Then, the last step is to start praying so Microsoft doesn't remove this too.